# Alignment of pointers to ints in GCC for Intel x64

Tags: c++, pointers, alignment

I need to add together several quadwords from some memory location:

```
uint64_t sum2 (const char * p, size_t n)
{
    uint64_t res = 0;
    const uint32_t * q = (const uint32_t*) p;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) res += q[i];
    return res;
}
```

I know that this code doesn't have to work on arbitrary C compiler on arbitrary machine. Not every pointer to `char` can be casted to a valid pointer to `int`. However, on Intel you can read 32-bit values from any address, in most cases even without any performance penalty, so this code should just work, regardless of the alignment of `p`. My program is running on 64-bit Intel Sandy Bridge, compiled using GCC 4.8 using `-msse4.2 -O3`.

This code SIGSEGVs when the address isn't 4-aligned. The reason is that the loop is unrolled four times and compiled using SSE. Four values are read together using MOVDQA, which requires alignment by 16. Before the loop, the pointer is aligned by 16, provided that it is already aligned by 4.

How can I prevent this SSE optimisation on GCC? I really need to add misaligned 32-bit numbers.

Comment: Maybe use `memcpy` to copy from `&q[i]` to a temporary.

Comment: UB on the second line. Why doing this?

Comment: It should not be vectorizing this code, p has no alignment and is a valid alias for anything at all.  You could try throwing in __builtin_assume_aligned(q, 1).  Do mention the version number.

Comment: Do you have control on how p was allocated? If so, just allocate with the correct alignment.

Answer (score 1):

It will probably have a performance penalty, but I think you need to use `memcpy` to copy to a temporary that's properly aligned.

```
uint64_t sum2 (const char * p, size_t n)
{
    uint64_t res = 0, temp;
    const uint32_t * q = (const uint32_t*) p;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        memcpy(&temp, &q[i], sizeof(*q));
        res += temp;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Hopefully it's not aligning `q` or `&q[i]`. If that's the case, you'll need to do the address arithmetic yourself.

```
uint64_t sum2 (const char * p, size_t n)
{
    uint64_t res = 0, temp;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++, p += sizeof(uint32_t)) {
        memcpy(&temp, p, sizeof(uint32_t));
        res += temp;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: memcpy is implemented as a compiler intrinsic on gcc thus the compiler can easily optimize it out if it feels like.

Comment: The memcpy version works surprisingly well, and the code it produces is surprisingly good. The memcpy is compiled into a single movl instruction (memory to register).

Comment: Do you need to use the second version?

Answer (score 1):

You could selectively control the optimisaton and code generation for a specific function, see 
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html

and 
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html

particularly:

```
__attribute__ ((target("no-sse2")))
uint64_t sum2 (const char * p, size_t n)
{
    uint64_t res = 0;
    const uint32_t * q = (const uint32_t*) p;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) res += q[i];
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Small correction: target name must be quoted and it should be no-sse2, since the generated code relied onluy on SSE2 instructions:

    __attribute__ ((target("no-sse2")))

Answer (score 1):

How about the best of both worlds in a standards-compliant manner?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>



uint64_t sum2_unaligned (const char * p, size_t n)
{
    uint64_t res = 0, temp;
    const uint32_t * q = (const uint32_t*) p;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        memcpy(&temp, &q[i], sizeof(*q));
        res += temp;
    }
    return res;
}

uint64_t sum2_aligned (const std::uint64_t * p, size_t n)
{
    uint64_t res = 0, temp;
    const uint32_t * q = (const uint32_t*) p;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        res += p[i];
    }
    return res;
}

uint64_t sum2 (const char* p, size_t n)
{
  constexpr auto alignment = alignof(std::uint64_t);
  void* mem = const_cast<void*>(reinterpret_cast<const void*>(p));
  std::size_t space = n * sizeof(std::uint64_t);
  auto mem2 = std::align(alignment, space, mem, space);
  if (mem2 != mem)
  {
    return sum2_unaligned(p, n);
  }
  else
  {
    return sum2_aligned(reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t const*>(p), n);
  }
}
```